# How do I configure a Fluent/MySQL database connection without putting my password in configure.swift in Vapor 3?

Tags: swift, vapor

The [Vapor 3 documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/mysql/getting-started/#customizing-config) doesn't say much about database configuration other than to "register a `DatabasesConfig` struct to your services."

Tutorials (such as [this one](https://medium.com/@martinlasek/tutorial-how-to-use-mysql-b0d6d5bd0bcd)) suggest that you implement the configuration in the `App/configure.swift` file like this:

```
let mysqlConfig = MySQLDatabaseConfig(
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "mycooldb"
)
services.register(mysqlConfig)
```

But my `configure.swift` file is being tracked by git, and I don't want to commit my username and password.

How do I supply an external configuration file for handling the database connection?

It appears that earlier versions of Vapor used JSON configuration files. Is this functionality completely gone? I can't find any mention of it in the current documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most popular way to do this is using environment variables. You can set them in the Xcode scheme or the terminal:

```
export DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Then get it in your configuration:

```
guard let password = Environment.get("DB_PASSWORD") else {
    throw Abort(.internalServerError)
}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear but it should be noted that this won't work for an iOS app, just macOS since you can't set environment variables for an iOS app other than during development using Xcode.

Comment: True, but that currently isn't an issue as Vapor doesn't even run on iOS at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an environment variable, and load it like:

```
Environment.get("MY_VAR")
```